# How to use the same javascript function on multiple HTML divs with the same class

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, web

So, I'm working on a website and I have a function that expands and contracts a div element upon button press - however I would like to have many of these same divs on the same page without making a separate JS file for each one. I was wondering what I need to do. The HTML, CSS, and JS follow with a brief explanation of what I'm doing:

So basically I have a bunch of classes in the HTML and then through the JS I target the projectDescriptionExpand class and toggle the show-more class. By doing this I change the display from 'none' to 'inline'. Now I'm trying to add another one of these rows in my HTML but I am not able to figure out how. I tried using querySelectorAll and running the JS through a for loop but that doesn't seem to work.

THANKS!!

HTML:

```
<!-- START OF THE PROJECT HIGHLIGHTS -->
    <div class="row projectHighlightHead greyHighlight">
        <!-- Project description and graphic row -->
        <div class="col-6 justify-content-center" style="padding-right: 7%"> 
            <div class="row"> 

                <!-- PROJECT NAME -->
                <h2 class="projectNameExpand">Project Name</h2>

                <div class="easyButtons"> 
                    <!-- DATE AND STATUS BUTTONS -->
                    <button class="yearStatus" disabled>20XX</button>
                    <button class="yearStatus" disabled>Status</button>
                </div>

                <p class="projectDescriptionExpand"> <strong> Brief project description.</strong> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sem neque venenatis dolor fermentum massa nec<span class="ellipse">...</span><span class="readMore">, auctor mi. Aliquet feugiat rhoncus, egestas integer ultricies facilisi sem neque dolor.</span></p>

                <button class="viewProject">View Project</button>

                <div class="collapsed"> 
                <!-- INSERT THE INSTAGRAM LINK IN THE QUOTE MARKS -->
                    <a href="LINK!!">  
                        <button class="instagramButton"><img style="max-width: 100%;" src="./assets/photos/insta_icon.png"></button>
                    </a> 

                    <a href="LINK!!"> 
                        <button class="projButtons">Case Study</button>
                    </a>

                    <a href="LINK!!"> 
                        <button class="projButtons">Project Link</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.greyHighlight {
  background-color: #f4f5f6;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 160px;
}

.whiteHighlight {
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 160px;
}

.projectNameExpand {
  font-size: 65px;
  font-family: GreycliffBold;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.expand {
  margin-left: -12%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.viewProject {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 30px;

  position: absolute;
  bottom: -80px;

  font-family: GreycliffBold;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.projectDescriptionExpand {
  font-family: GreycliffReg;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.readMore {
  display: none;
}

.show-more .readMore {
  display: inline;
}
.projectImageExpand {
  max-width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 10px -10px #66ffcc;
}
.projectDescription .ellipse {
  display: none;
}

.show-more .ellipse {
  display: none;
}
.collapsed {
  display: none;
}

.show-more {
  display: inline;
}

.projectHighlightHead {
  padding-left: 12%;
}
```

JS:

```
const viewProjectButton = document.querySelectorAll(".viewProject");
const projDescription = document.querySelectorAll("projectDescription");

for(var i = 0; i < viewProjectButton.length; i++) { 
    viewProjectButton[i].addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        document.getElementsByClassName(".projectDescriptionExpand").classList.toggle('show-more');
        document.getElementsByClassName(".collapsed").classList.toggle('show-more');

        if(viewProjectButton[i].innerText === "View Project") {
            viewProjectButton[i].innerText = "Close Project";
            viewProjectButton[i].style.color = "white";
            viewProjectButton[i].style.backgroundColor = "black";
        }
        else {
            viewProjectButton[i].innerText = "View Project";
            viewProjectButton[i].style.color = "black";
            viewProjectButton[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple event listeners — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. E.g., use an [event argument](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](/q/1687296/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than set listeners on each button, you can delegate and set one on `document`, then check to see if it is the button that is being clicked.

To find the associated elements to toggle, you can use `closest()` to find the common parent, then `querySelector` to hone in on the element itself. I added a class `.project` to define a parent tag.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.addEventListener('click', e => {
      if (e.target.classList.contains('viewProject')) {
        let myParent = e.target.closest('.project');
        myParent.querySelector('.collapsed').classList.toggle('show-more');
        myParent.querySelector('.projectDescriptionExpand').classList.toggle('show-more');
        if (myParent.querySelector('.collapsed').classList.contains('show-more')) {
          e.target.innerText = "Close Project";
          e.target.style.color = "white";
          e.target.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        } else {
          e.target.innerText = "View Project";
          e.target.style.color = "black";
          e.target.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
      }
    })
})
```

```css
.greyHighlight {
  background-color: #f4f5f6;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 160px;
}

.whiteHighlight {
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 160px;
}

.projectNameExpand {
  font-size: 65px;
  font-family: GreycliffBold;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.expand {
  margin-left: -12%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.viewProject {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -80px;
  font-family: GreycliffBold;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.projectDescriptionExpand {
  font-family: GreycliffReg;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.readMore {
  display: none;
}

.show-more .readMore {
  display: inline;
}

.projectImageExpand {
  max-width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 10px -10px #66ffcc;
}

.projectDescription .ellipse {
  display: none;
}

.show-more .ellipse {
  display: none;
}

.collapsed {
  display: none;
}

.show-more {
  display: inline;
}

.projectHighlightHead {
  padding-left: 12%;
}
```

```html
<!-- START OF THE PROJECT HIGHLIGHTS -->
<div class="row projectHighlightHead greyHighlight">
  <!-- Project description and graphic row -->
  <div class="col-6 justify-content-center" style="padding-right: 7%">
    <div class="row project">

      <!-- PROJECT NAME -->
      <h2 class="projectNameExpand">Project Name</h2>

      <div class="easyButtons">
        <!-- DATE AND STATUS BUTTONS -->
        <button class="yearStatus" disabled>20XX</button>
        <button class="yearStatus" disabled>Status</button>
      </div>

      <p class="projectDescriptionExpand"> <strong> Brief project description.</strong> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sem neque venenatis dolor fermentum massa nec<span class="ellipse">...</span><span class="readMore">, auctor mi. Aliquet feugiat rhoncus, egestas integer ultricies facilisi sem neque dolor.</span></p>

      <button class="viewProject">View Project</button>

      <div class="collapsed">
        <!-- INSERT THE INSTAGRAM LINK IN THE QUOTE MARKS -->
        <a href="LINK!!">
          <button class="instagramButton"><img style="max-width: 100%;" src="./assets/photos/insta_icon.png"></button>
        </a>

        <a href="LINK!!">
          <button class="projButtons">Case Study</button>
        </a>

        <a href="LINK!!">
          <button class="projButtons">Project Link</button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You could reduce the code further by setting an `active` class on `.project` and then having css rules that show/hide the elements wi

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('viewProject')) {
      e.target.closest('.project').classList.toggle('active');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.greyHighlight {
  background-color: #f4f5f6;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 160px;
}

.whiteHighlight {
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 160px;
}

.projectNameExpand {
  font-size: 65px;
  font-family: GreycliffBold;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.expand {
  margin-left: -12%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.viewProject {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -80px;
  font-family: GreycliffBold;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.projectDescriptionExpand {
  font-family: GreycliffReg;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.readMore {
  display: none;
}

.project.active .readMore {
  display: inline;
}

.projectImageExpand {
  max-width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 10px -10px #66ffcc;
}

.projectDescription .ellipse {
  display: none;
}

.project.active .projectDescription .ellipse {
  display: none;
}

.collapsed {
  display: none;
}

.project.active .collapsed {
  display: inline;
}

.projectHighlightHead {
  padding-left: 12%;
}

.viewProject {
  content: "View Project";
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}

.project.active .viewProject {
  content: "Close Project";
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<!-- START OF THE PROJECT HIGHLIGHTS -->
<div class="row projectHighlightHead greyHighlight">
  <!-- Project description and graphic row -->
  <div class="col-6 justify-content-center" style="padding-right: 7%">
    <div class="row project">

      <!-- PROJECT NAME -->
      <h2 class="projectNameExpand">Project Name</h2>

      <div class="easyButtons">
        <!-- DATE AND STATUS BUTTONS -->
        <button class="yearStatus" disabled>20XX</button>
        <button class="yearStatus" disabled>Status</button>
      </div>

      <p class="projectDescriptionExpand"> <strong> Brief project description.</strong> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sem neque venenatis dolor fermentum massa nec<span class="ellipse">...</span><span class="readMore">, auctor mi. Aliquet feugiat rhoncus, egestas integer ultricies facilisi sem neque dolor.</span></p>

      <button class="viewProject">View Project</button>

      <div class="collapsed">
        <!-- INSERT THE INSTAGRAM LINK IN THE QUOTE MARKS -->
        <a href="LINK!!">
          <button class="instagramButton"><img style="max-width: 100%;" src="./assets/photos/insta_icon.png"></button>
        </a>

        <a href="LINK!!">
          <button class="projButtons">Case Study</button>
        </a>

        <a href="LINK!!">
          <button class="projButtons">Project Link</button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment above, it's best to use event delegation, to `delegate` the event from the document node to your `viewProject` node. You do that by just checking if the current target has the class `viewProject`.

`getElementsByClassName` requires the class name without the `.` and then you select the first element you get by using `[0]`

`if condition` checks with `innerText`, are not that good because if the text changes, then your code breaks. It's best to use data html attributes for that.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('viewProject')) {
    clickViewProject(event.target)
  }
})

function clickViewProject (node) {
  const desc = document.getElementsByClassName('projectDescriptionExpand')[0]
  desc.classList.toggle('show-more')
  const collapsed = document.getElementsByClassName('collapsed')[0]
  collapsed.classList.toggle('show-more')
  
  // .. add the rest of the code
  if (node.innerText === "View Project") {
    node.innerText = "Close Project"
    node.style.color = "white"
    node.style.backgroundColor = "black"
  } else {
    node.innerText = "View Project"
    node.style.color = "black"
    node.style.backgroundColor = "white"
  }
}
```

```css
.greyHighlight {
  background-color: #f4f5f6;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 160px;
}

.whiteHighlight {
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 160px;
}

.projectNameExpand {
  font-size: 65px;
  font-family: GreycliffBold;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.expand {
  margin-left: -12%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.viewProject {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 30px;

  position: absolute;
  bottom: -80px;

  font-family: GreycliffBold;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.projectDescriptionExpand {
  font-family: GreycliffReg;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.readMore {
  display: none;
}

.show-more .readMore {
  display: inline;
}
.projectImageExpand {
  max-width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 10px -10px #66ffcc;
}
.projectDescription .ellipse {
  display: none;
}

.show-more .ellipse {
  display: none;
}
.collapsed {
  display: none;
}

.show-more {
  display: inline;
}

.projectHighlightHead {
  padding-left: 12%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row projectHighlightHead greyHighlight">
        <!-- Project description and graphic row -->
        <div class="col-6 justify-content-center" style="padding-right: 7%"> 
            <div class="row"> 

                <!-- PROJECT NAME -->
                <h2 class="projectNameExpand">Project Name</h2>

                <div class="easyButtons"> 
                    <!-- DATE AND STATUS BUTTONS -->
                    <button class="yearStatus" disabled>20XX</button>
                    <button class="yearStatus" disabled>Status</button>
                </div>

                <p class="projectDescriptionExpand"> <strong> Brief project description.</strong> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sem neque venenatis dolor fermentum massa nec<span class="ellipse">...</span><span class="readMore">, auctor mi. Aliquet feugiat rhoncus, egestas integer ultricies facilisi sem neque dolor.</span></p>

                <button class="viewProject">View Project</button>

                <div class="collapsed"> 
                <!-- INSERT THE INSTAGRAM LINK IN THE QUOTE MARKS -->
                    <a href="LINK!!">  
                        <button class="instagramButton"><img style="max-width: 100%;" src="./assets/photos/insta_icon.png"></button>
                    </a> 

                    <a href="LINK!!"> 
                        <button class="projButtons">Case Study</button>
                    </a>

                    <a href="LINK!!"> 
                        <button class="projButtons">Project Link</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```